# Encrypt the password in Openssl Command

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

Currently, I am supplying the password in plaintext format as below:

openssl genrsa -aes128 -passout pass:**foobar** 3072

Where `foobar` is the password supplied in plaintext format .

I want to supply the password using some encrypted format or any other way such that its not easily readable .

Comment: As Jay correctly says, you can't encrypt the passphrase. There are several ways of having it not readable, depending on exactly which kind(s) of readable you care about, but they are described in the man pages which you read before asking, and obviously they were unsuitable for some reason(s) you don't explain, making it impossible to try to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed did supply the password in an encrypted format as you are requesting, how will provide the encryption key which was used to encrypt the said password to OpenSSL so that OpenSSL can decrypt it and use the correct password?

The password which you are providing to OpenSSL, I assume, is used by OpenSSL to encrypt the RSA Private Key which will be generated. If this is indeed the password which you want OpenSSL to use, then it has to be given in plaintext.

If you are worried that it might be seen by someone, you need to ensure that it is entered in a secure way. But, "encrypted password" is not the solution, as you might end up with a complication of protecting the encryption key for the password itself.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the password should be passed via openssl prompt (i.e.: removing the `-passout pass:foobar` argument).

If you're passing the password via command line because you have to use it in another part of the script, you can use the example below:

```
echo -n Password: 
read -s PASS
openssl genrsa -out keypair.pem -aes128 -passout pass:${PASS}
opnessl req -new -key keypair.pem -passin pass:${PASS}
```

However, if you really need to generate keys without user interaction, you can use the example bellow, but I wouldn't recommend it for any production environment.

Create a script (e.g.: auto_key_gen.sh) containing the code bellow:

```
PASS=`openssl rand -hex 16`
openssl genrsa -out auto_keypair.pem -aes128 -passout pass:${PASS}
echo -n ${PASS} | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey $1 -out encrypted_pass.bin
```

Generate a personal keypair and extract the public key:

```
openssl genrsa -out mykeypair.pem -aes128
openssl rsa -in mykeypair.pem -out mypubkey.pem -pubout
```

Keep the personal keypair somewhere safe. The personal public key, you use to run the script:

```
chmod +x auto_key_gen.sh
./auto_key_gen.sh mypubkey.pem
```

The script generates a random password and uses it to encrypt the generated key pair (auto_keypair.pem). The password is encrypted with your personal public key and saved in a file (encrypted_pass.bin).

The script can keep the password in "memory" to use with other openssl commands.

You can retrieve the encrypted password using your personal keypair:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey mykeypair.pem -in encrypted_pass.bin -out decrypted_pass.hex
```

Both the script and the public key must be protected against unauthorized modification.